# How can I add a testId attribute to a React Native component for Testing Library when TypeScript prevents me?

Tags: typescript, react-native, react-native-testing-library

I'm writing a React Native components using TypeScript and testing them with [React Native Testing Library](https://testing-library.com/docs/react-native-testing-library/intro/).

I want to put a testId attribute on a React Native component like so:

```
<TextInput testId="foo" />
```

And then refer to it in a test like so:

```
it('receives a search string', () => {
  const { getByTestId } = render(<FooComponent />);;
  const textBox = getByTestId("foo");
  fireEvent.changeText(textBox,"some fake text");
  expect(textBox.value).toEqual("some fake text");
});
```

But TypeScript won't allow me to put a `testId` attribute on a  component because of course, TypeScript is asking React Native about valid attributes and React Native knows nothing about a `testId`; testId is part of @testing-library/react-native.

How do I get TypeScript to recognize the added attributes like `testId` from @testing-library/react-native.

Answer (score 3):

Found the problem. `testId` should have been `testID`. Simple typo on my part.

If anyone finds this, the problem is not that that TypeScript isn't aware of the `testID` attribute at all. You don't need to `npm install @types/whatever`. They're already recognized as part of installing RNTL.